# Windows 8.1 - camera app poor framerate

Tags: windows-8.1, webcam

The Windows 8.1 native camera app started acting weird: when turning it on it shows the camera image with an incredibly small framerate of around **2-3 fps**, instead of the usual smooth 18-30fps.

When I open the camera in some other application like **Skype** or **OpenBroadcasterSoftware** everything works just fine so it's clearly not the hardware webcam problem.

When you click on the video button inside the windows camera app - the image jumps to the normal framerate aswell, but only until you end with making the video and go back to the photo mode; the pics themselve also end up alright, only the experience of making them ain't the best because of the sucky framerate.

The camera app wasn't always weird like this, it used to have the solid framerate until something like a month ago when it has changed completely spontaneously, I can't recall any program installation or other event that could be the cause.

I'm using **Windows 8.1 Pro** and the **Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920**.
Any help on fixing this highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall it then reinstall it?  I am pretty sure you can do this even with the default Windows 8 applications.

Comment: couldn't really find/google the way to uninstall the native camera app. pretty much everywhere it says it's impossible